# MySQL Transaction doesn't rollback with 0 affected rows - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I tried to make my first query return `affected rows: 0` to see if the transaction fails but it continued executing the second query.

Should i break the transaction manually?

```php
DB::transaction(function () {
  User::where('id', 1002)->update(['name' => 'x']); // id:1002 doesn't exist

  Post::where('user_id', 1)->update(['title' => 'New Title']);
});
```

Comment: why would it fail?

Comment: It's not failing, it just doesn't find anything to update. You might want to check for affected rows on the first query before attempting the second.

Comment: @aynber What if the given id exists but MySQL still returns 0 somehow for any reason, can that happen?

Comment: @lagbox Please read my comment above.

Comment: That could happen if there's no change. So if 1002 exists, but the name is already x, then there are no affected rows.

Comment: Can you show some context around this? Is it a controller method?

Comment: @miken32 Yes it's in controller method using Eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot of context around your sample code, but a very basic approach would be something like this:

```php
$user = User::findorFail(1002);
$user->update(['name' => 'x']);
if ($user->wasChanged('name')) {
    Post::where('user_id', 1)->update(['title' => 'New Title']);
}
```

So the first line will throw an exception if the model isn't found. Then we do an update. You specifically said you were checking for 0 affected rows, so next we use [the `wasChanged()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes). It "determines if any attributes were changed when the model was last saved within the current request cycle." If that's the case, we proceed with the next update.

There are other changes that could be made involving, for example, [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) if there was more of your code shown in the question, but hopefully this is a helpful start.